# Where JasperStudio stores .jrxml files?

Tags: jaspersoft-studio

I am migrating from Jasper 5.5.x to 6.4.0, using Jaspersoft Studio (no more iReport), but I noticed that after modifying a few reports, JRXML files are not modified (at least not in the folder where .jrxml and .jasper are, from where I opened it). they are in the "workspace".
How can I make Studio to save the jrxml in the same place that .jaspers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually they are saved in the same folder but I don't have experience in migrating from iReport. 
You can change the directory where Jasersoft Studio saves the files by right-clicking on your project in the Project Explorer and selecting Properties.
On the left side you select Resources->Linked Resources. Under Path Variables you can set the PROJECT_LOC variable.

Hope this helps

Comment: I don't have the "Project Explorer" tab, just Outline, Repository, Properties and Palette. In the Properties tab of an opened report, I don't see any prop related to resources.


PD: I still didn't figure it out a few concepts in this new IDE like: "working set" (type Resource or Java), "workspace", Projects. I usually have many reports opened from different projects at the same time

Comment: Try Window->Reset perspective. This will reset the GUI to the default settings. The Project Explorer Tab should be right of the Repository Explorer. Jaspersoft Studio is based on the Eclipse IDE. So most Eclipse tricks work with Jaspersoft Studio